# Fastboot не видит девайс

Tags: windows-7, adb, samsung

Fastboot не видит телефон, хотя adb прекрасно работает.

При попытке написать в командную строку `fastboot devices` ничего не выдает.

В fastboot mode захожу командой `adb reboot-bootloader`.

Кабель usb исправен. Драйвера установил, отладку по usb включил и разрешил. Выбрал использование usb для передачи файлов. OEM разблокировал. Скачал adb и fastboot  через [установщик](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-2-9-18.2317790/).

Телефон Samsung Galaxy J5 Prime на Android 8.

Пк на Windows 7.

Comment: А что именно вам надо от fastboot? Обычно, Самсунги шьются одином.

Comment: Разблокировать bootloader

Comment: Извини, если глупый вопрос. Два дня назад рутировал смартфон и мне стало интересно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто: Bootloader != fastboot --> это разные режимы; а adb reboot-bootloader у большинства телефонов вообще ведет в рекавери(то где factory-reset и которое перешивается на twrp). По моему опыту шил Samsungи исключительно через их загрузочный режим(красные буквы на бирюзовом фоне, заходил через кнопки) утилитами на основе ODIN
Встречный вопрос , так как Samsung !=  Xiaomi как ты получил OEM без махинаций с прошивками и jtag

Comment: В параметрах разрабочика "Разблокировка предусмотренная производитлем", "Разрешить разблокирование, предусмотренное производителем OEM". Спасибо, что пояснил про bootloader.

Comment: Это другое: это означает что теперь через утилиту а-ля ODIN ты сможешь ввести код разблокировки загрузчика(в случае Samsung!=bootloader(обычно ==)), только этот код для твоего серийного номера телефона еще надо добыть.

Comment: У Xiaomi это тривиально, но надо ждать 14дней(антикража?)

Comment: У Huawei  коды продаются на сторонних сайтах, но стоят значительных денег(frp через них невыгодно)